# Can't rotate Image when button is clicked more than once

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewanimation, cgaffinetransform

I am trying to Rotate an ImageView every time the button is clicked. It only rotates for the first time the button is clicked, otherwise it is nonchalant

```
- (IBAction)btnRotate:(id)sender
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionNone animations:^
    {
        CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI);
        self.image.transform = transform;
    } completion:NULL];
}
```

Also I want to rotate image from the state it was last rotated, I mean, if I rotate image to 90 degrees, when the button is clicked next time, the image should rotate from 90 degrees to 180 degrees.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this :

```
CGAffineTransform transform = self.image.transform;
CGAffineTransform transform_new = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, M_PI);
self.image.transform = transform_new;
```

instead of :

```
CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI);
self.image.transform = transform;
```

Every time you press the button, you need to take into consideration the previous rotation.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are only setting M_PI as the transformation, the transformation is applied to the original image so no matter how many times you click the button it will always be 90. What you need to do is get the current transformation and add it to the transformation you want to apply. So on each click of the button the transformation will go from 90->180->270 etc

Comment: Can you help me with that? I am new to animation

Answer (score 0):

This code will help you.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionNone animations:^
 {
     CGFloat angle = [(NSNumber *)[self.image valueForKeyPath:@"layer.transform.rotation.z"] floatValue];

     CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angle+M_PI_2);
     self.image.transform = transform;
 } completion:NULL];
```